# Is there an equivalent of .ssh/config for use with psql?

Tags: linux, psql

In the `.ssh/config` file (at least that's the usual default location), I can define hostname, username, port, etc. for ssh connections and store it with an easy to use name. That allows me to call `ssh` or `scp` without having to do all the tedious typing, but just hit e.g. `ssh myconnection2`.

Is there an equivalent for this functionality in `psql`? The man page mentions the `.psqlrc` file in terms of configuration, which is not quite what I need, because it's sourced only after `psql` is started.

The only halfway decent workaround I have so far is to use `alias`, but that comes with problems of its own in some cases. Any ideas if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, the connection service file: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html